# How to use sub methods properly

Tags: java, methods, subprocess

I want to do an operation for calculating Body Mass Index in my CalBMI method, which depends on the inputs for CalWt and CalHt methods. Then the CalBMI method will return a BMI answer. How can I do such operation?The operation in my CalBMI

```
import java.util.*;   
public class PracticeMethods_returningValues {
static Scanner type=new Scanner(System.in);
public static void main(String[] args)
```

{

```
    double Wt=0, Ht=0, BMI;

    System.out.println("Your Weight in Kg is: " + CalWt(Wt) );
    System.out.println("Your Height in meters is: " + CalHt(Ht) );
    System.out.println("Your BMI is: " + CalBMI(Wt,Ht) );


    }


    public static double CalWt(double a){
    System.out.println("Please enter your Weight in lbs: ");
    double Wt=(type.nextDouble() * .454); //Converts to Kg.
    return Wt; 

    }


    public static double CalHt(double b){
    System.out.println("\nPlease enter your Height in inches: ");
    double Ht=(type.nextDouble() * .025); //Converts to m.
    return Ht;  
    }


    public static double CalBMI(double a, double b){
    double BMI=a/(Math.pow(b, 2));
    return BMI;
    }
```

}

Comment: yes they all can be called in main method use object

Comment: **tip** instead of creating `scanner` object in every method pass one `scanner object` to every method

Comment: Can you teach me? l'm a self learner Java guy. I learn from the advice I get me and videos here an there. Believe me I'll pay it forward!...

Comment: actually I'm not able to understand your question properly... if you can edit it so a simple noob can understand , it is possible that you will get answer fast

Comment: Ok, my apologies. I will do that.

Comment: can you tell me how are you going to calculate body mass index (formula)

Comment: I just edited the code to what I have so far. the formula is the weight divided by the height squared.

Comment: please check my answer , I posted

Comment: Thanks a lot man. I figured it out. This is advance for me, didn't know I could do such things.

Comment: you will do, now if you got solution you can accept the answer

Comment: click tick and you are done

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please tell me if the formula is wrong

```
 public class BMI {

        public static double CalWt(Scanner type) {
            System.out.println("Please enter your Weight in lbs: ");
            return type.nextDouble() * .45359;
        }

        public static double CalHt(Scanner type) {
            System.out.println("Please enter your Height in inches: ");
            return type.nextDouble()* .025;
        }

        public static double CalBMI() {
            Scanner type = new Scanner(System.in);
            return CalWt(type) / Math.pow(CalHt(type),2);
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(CalBMI());
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's right on point. But in order to calculate BMI, you don't input anything, you simply calculated based of of your Weight and Height (Wt, Ht). Thus I need my BMI to be a calculation not an input.

Comment: how you will provide input

Comment: `But in order to calculate BMI, you don't input anything` check `calBMI()` method it does the trick

Comment: why do you have a Scanner within CalBMI then?

Comment: like I said it is better to create one object and pass to every possible method instead of creating it in every method

Comment: also what do you mean overtime you type in "type"...you mean double, string, int?

Comment: (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) read this and it look at signature `type.nextDouble()`